# Kubectl get pods doent come up on one particular node

Tags: docker, kubernetes, openshift, nodes, kubectl

I have a cluster with two nodes and one master, suddenly one of our node is not taking any pods even though both show as ready when I fire command kubectl get nodes.

```
#kubectl get node -o wide

server1   Ready     246d      v1.7.6+a08f5eeb62   <none>        Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.7 (Maipo)   3.10.0-1062.1.1.el7.x86_64

server2   Ready     246d      v1.7.6+a08f5eeb62   <none>        Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.6 (Maipo)   3.10.0-957.21.2.el7.x86_64
```

I have found partial problem but dont know how to fix it, when I fire below command, I get following output

awx-162-vzrw5    4/4       Running   0          1d        10.128.1.215   server1

nginx-1-deploy   0/1       Error     0          16m       10.129.1.149   server2

....

```
apiVersion: v1

kind: Node

metadata:

  annotations:

    volumes.kubernetes.io/controller-managed-attach-detach: "true"
  creationTimestamp: 2019-03-12T19:53:46Z
  labels:

    app: sysdig-agent
    beta.kubernetes.io/arch: amd64
    beta.kubernetes.io/os: linux
    kubernetes.io/hostname: server
    type: infra
  name: server

  resourceVersion: "31513319"
  selfLink: /api/v1/nodes/server
  uid: 8c57c6fa-4500-11e9-9f0e-0050569d26cf
spec:
  externalID: server

status:

  addresses:

  - address: 11.68.5.165

    type: InternalIP
  - address: server
    type: Hostname

  allocatable:

    cpu: "16"
    memory: 32668456Ki

    pods: "160"
  capacity:

    cpu: "16"
    memory: 32770856Ki

    pods: "160"

  - names:
    - docker.io/ansible/awx_rabbitmq@sha256:3ff448f979149a0684c61b0f00eb0fe7bc480b123323aa80fb3bb8934027f895
    - docker.io/ansible/awx_rabbitmq:3.7.4
    sizeBytes: 85570222
  - names:
    - docker.io/memcached@sha256:1e9858a576c76dc4d34d7f30318f89868127ac3dbf20b472645e8eb8e11cce02
    - docker.io/memcached:latest
    sizeBytes: 82206395

  nodeInfo:

    architecture: amd64

    bootID: 51af6b12-e490-4709-a434-31a04dcf635d

    containerRuntimeVersion: docker://1.13.1

    kernelVersion: 3.10.0-1062.1.1.el7.x86_64

    kubeProxyVersion: v1.7.6+a08f5eeb62

    kubeletVersion: v1.7.6+a08f5eeb62

    machineID: 04fbce323fd847e8bcc3f3d9e8272708

    operatingSystem: linux

    osImage: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.7 (Maipo)

    systemUUID: 389E1D42-F025-4083-5CB9-24F0743CDFB9
```

Comment: check the current number of pod allocated on "broken" node. compare it to "status.allocatable.pods"  value... or any other resources quotas.

Comment: can you describe the node that has no pods on it

Comment: Could you add the yaml of your non schedulable node in the question? `kubectl get node <node_name> -o yaml`

Comment: Kubectl describe node output
Namespace           Name                              CPU Requests    CPU Limits      Memory Requests Memory Limits
openshift-infra   prometheus-node-exporter-m69jt   100m (0%)       200m (1%)       30Mi (0%)       50Mi (0%)
sysdig-agent     sysdig-agent-tfrxv               100m (0%)       0 (0%)          512Mi (1%)      1Gi (3%)
Events:
FirstSeen  LastSeen Count   From            SubObjectPath   Type   Reason          Message
1h         1h       1       kubelet, server              Normal   NodeSchedulable Node server status is now: NodeSchedulable

Comment: Though it is suppose to have rabbitmq, awx_web, awx_task and memcashed running on node but they dont come up at all. Yaml above shows rabbitmq and all the containers but they dont appear in pods on node.

Comment: Could you please remove the comment and add it properly by modifying the Question?

Comment: @Ezwig, I have added yaml output in question, could you please look into it. Thanks

Comment: @OhHiMark, I copied partially as its too big to copy in question, I have not edited yml but I guess its same in both nodes, one node has 4 pods running but other dont take even one.

Comment: We still need more details in order to investigate. Check what Oleg is suggesting in the first comment. Delete your comment with 'kubectl describe node' output and edit the question instead. And generally try to provide more info that could help us investigate.

Comment: @OhHiMark, I have added another output, it seems to be a networking issue, I am not able to telnet from broken node to openshift api, I am not able to curl also. it says Failed connect to 172.30.0.1:443; No route to host. Though it was working fine sometime ago.